# Does this qualify as Filename Upload DOM-XSS?

Tags: xss, self-xss

An application has the following javascript code which is triggered whenever an user tries to upload a file.

```
a.html(fileName)
```

then if the user uploads a file named `<img src=x onerror=alert()>` the javascript code is executed.

Does this qualify as a Low-severity DOM-XSS? I mean, usually I see DOM-XSS which exploit URL giving more strength to the attack. In this case I should trick a user to upload a file with a specific name, so it's like a self-xss. Also, I couldn't find a cve for this kind of DOM-XSS.

Comment: it's much easier to use devtools to run code client-side. I don't see how this could inadvertently jeopardize a real user in the real world. FWIF, you should use `a.text(fileName)` to avoid such XSS.

Comment: Triggered via onchange of value attribute would be a little more insecure. .. more secure if the filename comes from a resource URL or event.files... since you should know the user has selected a file at that point instead of XSS changing the input's value.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, yes, this is a low to very low severity example of XSS. User-controlled input is rendered insecurely.

The fact that this requires a user to upload a specially crafted file, reduces the likelihood of abuse, not the impact.

People are the weakest link in cybersecurity. They can be tricked into uploading any file.